# Cordova Plugin crashes the app on launch

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, cordova

I'm having some problems with MC-Cordova-Plugin.
When I install it, it crashes the app.

Whithout it the app runs seamlessly. With the plugin installed, I can build it with no problems, but when I try to start the app the app crashes before showing up.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or what's causing it?
I've followed the installing process on the Github and NPM, all dependencies are on the supported versions.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What platform is crashing? Do you have a stacktrace? Did you follow the setup instructions?

Comment: @murilo, in addition to gathering the information Seth has requested, please be sure to log a support request with your Marketing Cloud representative.

We will be much better able to track, respond and be held accountable to you (and all our customers) needs via customer support.

Of course, continue to raise questions and concerns here - the MobilePush SDK team is happy to help in any way we can.